# Is the exercice in this schoolbook correct?

Tags: probability

As we are currently confined in France, I spend more time reviewing the homework of my children. We are stuck on one of the exercices.

The exercise is about basic probability.

> We know that
>   $$ P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B}) = 0.85 \\ P(A) = 2 \times P(B)$$
>   Calculate $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

My approach was to

$$
P(\overline{A \cap B}) = 1 - P(A \cap B) = 1 - [P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)]
$$

So

$$
P(A) + P(B) = 1 + P(A \cup B) - P(\overline{A \cap B})
$$

Using information from the exercise statements

\begin{align}
2 \times P(B) + P(B) &= 1 + P(A \cup B) - P(\overline{A \cap B}) \\
3 \times P(B) &= 1 + 0 \\
P(B) &= \frac{1}{3} \\
P(A) &= 2 \times P(B) = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

I got to that point without using the $= 0.85$ part, so I made a mistake somewhere. Where is it?

---

Note: I am not sure whether I should add the `homework` tag because, yes, this is part of the school exercises but is rather a question from a parent about the correctness of my thinking vs the exercice statements. Feel free to update if appropriate.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct: $[P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B}) \land P(A) = 2P(B)] \implies [P(B) = 1 / 3 \land P(A) = 2/3]$. Also your right to worry that in general the hypothesis "$[P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B}) \land P(A) = 2P(B)]$" might be false (however, the hypothesis is realisable in particular when common value is 0.85). My guess is that the person tutor who posed the question isn't aware that the condition "$=0.85$" is **either** redundant **or else** it is inconsistent :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes your solution is correct. Here is an alternative approach: Since $P(\overline{A\cap B})=0.85$, then $$P(A\cap B)=1-P(\overline{A\cap B})=0.15$$
Now use $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ 
That is

\begin{align}
0.85&=P(A\cup B)\\
0.85&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\
0.85&=2P(B)+P(B)-0.15\\
1&=3P(B)
\end{align}
So $P(B)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $P(A)=\frac{2}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

You have used that

> $P(\overline{A \cap B}) = 1 - [P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)]$

Unconsciously you have used that $P(A)+P(B)=1$ which is the same as

$P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B})\quad (*)$

et vice versa. But this is not true if another event $\color{red}C$ is involved. You can construct a counterexample where $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1$ and you will see that $(*)$ does not hold in general.

**Update:**

> $2 \times P(B) + P(B) = 1 + P(A \cup B) - P(\overline{A \cap B}) \\ 3
>  \times P(B) = 1 + 0$

Here you used that $P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B})$. That´s it. It is true that the value $0.85$ does not play a role here.

Comment: I do not understand the part "Unconsciously you have used that $P(A)+P(B)=1$". At which moment? I only used $P(\bar{X}) = 1 - P(X)$ and $P(X \cap Y) = P(X) + P(Y) - P(X \cup Y)$ (this is not my territory of choice so sorry if my question is obvious)

Comment: $P(\overline{A \cap B}) = 1 - [P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)]$ is only true if $P(A)+P(B)=1$ or equivalently $P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B})$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand why this is required? Both transformations I mentioned in my previous comment are independent of each other and none of them assume that $P(A)+P(B)=1$. I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Regarding your update: sorry if I come as demanding, but I would really like to understand that "unconscious" part you mentioned. I used $P(A \cup B) = P(\overline{A \cap B})$ because that was given in the statement of the exercise (the part after "We know that ..."). I understand that you can **derive from there** that $P(A)+P(B)=1$ (as a collateral information) but that was not used anywhere.